# TCAS II manoeuvres?

Tags: aircraft-systems, autopilot, tcas

What manoeuvres does the TCAS II advise the pilot to make?
Is it RA or TA ?

Answer (score 2):

The resolution advisories (RA) are the actual instructions that the TCAS system will give to the pilot.

Traffic Advisory (TA) only means the pilot needs to attempt to make visual contact and maintain visual separation if possible and prepare to respond to RA.

The [actual instructions that the TCAS gives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_collision_avoidance_system#Types_of_traffic_and_resolution_advisories) will to adjust the vertical speed, either by climbing, descending or leveling off.

There was some research conducted into adding turns into the RA however the directional antennas used by TCAS are not accurate enough to do this reliably.